# How to access position of a mobile node in inet framework?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to access position and speed of mobile nodes that use a mobility model in inet framework. I previously used `MobilityAccess.h` library to use the methods defined in the form

```
MobilityAccess().get(module)->getCurrentPosition()
```

This method is possible for `inet 2.6` framework. I need to use an updated version of `inet 3.2.1`, but in this version `MobilityAccess.h` library does not exist or moved to another place.

I checked `inet 3.2.1` folders, there is `base` folder instead of `common` folder that used to be in `inet 2.6` folder of `mobility` in `src`.

Is there any way to get the position of a mobile node in `inet 3.2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 cModule *host = getContainingNode(this);
 IMobility *mobility = check_and_cast<IMobility *>(host->getSubmodule("mobility"));
 ... = mobility->getCurrentPosition();
```

Comment: A bit of description: getContainingNode(this) travels up inthe hierarchy until it finds a node with the property @networkNode, then the mobility submodule is accessed and converted to IMobility so location data can be accessed. Note the this code fails if a module does not have a mobility configured.